# Importing jars in kotlin REPL

Tags: gradle, kotlin

In a project managed by gradle, how to import an installed package in kotlin REPL ?

```
Welcome to Kotlin version 1.0.3 (JRE 1.8.0_05-b13)
Type :help for help, :quit for quit
>>> import com.vladsch.flexmark.*
error: unresolved reference: vladsch
import com.vladsch.flexmark.*
           ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Kotlin 1.1.1, there is no support to do this automatically. You need to pass the classpath to the `kotlinc` command manually:

```
 kotlinc -cp build/classes/main
```

Comment: So assuming that a package `"com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-all:0.18.5"` is specified as a dependency in `build.gradle`, what should the cp argument be?  Trying `build/classes/main` and `~/.gradle` does not work.

Comment: You should specify the exact path to this jar file. You can find the jar in the ~/.gradle directory.